# SharePoint 2013 Search: Combining external site search results with a site subscription

Tags: search, multi-tenancy, content-source, crawl-external-content

I have a host header site collection that is part of a site subscription.  This trims search results to only show results from within its subscription.

I am needing to crawl an external source (in this case using the "Web Sites" content source) and include those results with the rest of the tenant's site subscription results.

### I have these two content sources:

Local SharePoint sites - **[SharePoint Sites Content Source Type]**
External Site - **[Web Sites Content Source Type]**

The **Local SharePoint sites** includes a single web app with many host header site collections, each a part of a site subscription.

The **External Site** is a seperate SaaS solution with content that I want to show in one of the site collection's search results.

**Is it possible to include any externally crawled sites into a site's search results when part of a site subscription?**

I have tested and see that results from the **External Site** do show when searched from a site that is not part of a site subscription.

Comment: You are doing an on-prem multi-tenant farm? Did you provision the SSA and the Proxy with partitions?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott Thank you for your response.  Yes we are using the "UniquePartitionPerSubscription" partition option on the SSA.

Comment: What are you seeing in the Crawl Log for the Content Source? You say its a solution of yours. Is authentication working?

Comment: The crawl logs are showing 7 successes, 10 warnings and no errors.  The solution is a third party SaaS solution.  When I use this content source with a non-tenant site, it will return the crawled results, so I know the crawl is working.  The warnings are mostly about unsupported formats such as pngs and permanently moved URLs.

Comment: I have not set up an on-prem multitenant environment, I talk my clients out of it. I would open a ticket with Microsoft and find out if your scenario is supported.